# Qt4 child thread edit Gui on mainthread

Tags: qt4, qt4.7

I have a tablewidget which needs to be appended with data from a child thread.

I get this error *It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread*. In c# I used a Disptacher to tell the mainThread to append data in a gui object.

I assume there is some how something close to this? Am using qt4.7
I  have made a slot in the parent and a signal within the thread object.. an emit signal from the child thread to send a signal to a slot in the parent. but the signal is not firing. when i execute the method like so object->run(); (i.e from mainthread) it works fine.. but when i execute it from the thread object->start(); the signal is not fired.. i neeed to do somework with a thread not in mainthread..

**UPDATE--27/09**
i just got to the root of the problem.. the signal and slot are working but the child thread is lauching a qnetworkaccessmanger object that is causing all this trouble.. i commented the networkaccess object and no error.. I need the thread to call a network request.. and update the results in the gui..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [Qt's signal/slot mechanism](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/signalsandslots.html) with a connection type of [Qt::QueuedConnection](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum). This queues the call to the slot in the thread the receiver object lives in automatically.

Comment: also.. i have a bunch of threads not just one that will be appending data..so i have created a slot in the parent.. and emittted the signal from the thread. i tried moving a pointer of the parent to the thread class but.. i cant do that it says..                          QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.

Comment: oh.. am changing something... i realized i don't need the parent reference in the child..

Comment: I made a slot in the parent and a signal within the thread object.. an emit signal from the child thread to send a signal to a slot in the parent.. this doesn't work too. it brings the same error "It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread". when i do object->run(); without saying object->start(); it runs fine on the main thread. but object->start(); lauches error..

Comment: Sounds like you somehow still work with the pixmap in the non-UI thread. It would be helpful if you could post some _minimal_ example code.

Comment: i just got to the root of the problem.. the signal and slot are working but the child thread is lauching a qnetworkaccessmanger object that is causing all this trouble.. i commented the networkaccess object and no error.. I need the thread to call a network request.. and update the results in the gui..

Comment: okay i resolved... i was using a qeventloop object in the child.. i removed it.. and voila.. works like clock work.
but I had to manager->moveToThread(this) at the child.. even thou i created the manager at the child.